# True or false? Any finite problem is in P

Tags: complexity-theory

Please explain to me if this is true or false. I had this in an exam, and I really need to know if I got this correct. I believe it is true because finite problems have finite solutions, which can be done in polynomial time.

Comment: Are you talking about decision problems?

Comment: What do you mean by finite problem? the one that can be defined in constant number of bits?

Answer (score 0):

If by finite problem, you mean a problem with a finite domain, then yes. Such problems are not only in P, but can be done in constant time since you can build a mapping between every possible input and its correct output.

Comment: I am not sure about constant time, since you would need to read the input to map to the answer correctly.

Comment: @Nathaniel, If we are talking about finite **languages**, then reading roughly as much input as the length of the longest accepted word (i.e., a constant) suffices.

Comment: @Steven You are right, of course!